# Displayed Math in tikz-cd diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, symbols, diagrams

I have been using tikz-cd package to produce diagrams however I'm not finding a way to use displayed math within it. My point is that when I use the product sign for instance inside of it, it simply shows as it were inline. I'm using the following commands:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
     \centering
     \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
          \prod_{i=1}^{p} \arrow{r}{i} \arrow[bend right=50]{rr}{T} & \mathcal{M} \arrow{r}{\pi} & \otimes_{i=1}^{p}V_i
     \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}
```

However both the normal product sign and the tensor product sign appear as inline. Is there any way to show those signs as they appear in the displaymath mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\displaystyle\prod` and `\bigotimes\limits`; I also used a `shorten` length for the curved arrow to prevent overlapping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
          \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{p} \arrow{r}{i} \arrow[bend right=50,shorten >=10pt]{rr}{T} & \mathcal{M} \arrow{r}{\pi} & \bigotimes\limits_{i=1}^{p}V_i
     \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a neat option or workarround in tikz-cd to make it work for all diagrams?

Answer (score 0):

`\displaystyle` and `\limits` will probably do what you want.

Try, for example, `$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n}\limits a_i$`.

Comment: Hi @user12677, it worked just for \prod, for \otimes it doesn't work. Is any workaround? Thanks very much.

Comment: Try ``\bigotimes``

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be use the math display environment. Try

```
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
      \prod_{i=1}^{p} \arrow{r}{i} \arrow[bend right=50]{rr}{T} & \mathcal{M} \arrow{r}{\pi} & \otimes_{i=1}^{p}V_i
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Although it's placed within a display math environment, the `\prod` still appears to be the inline form with this snippet.  I think the elements of the `tikzcd` are placed inside nodes enclosed by `$`, kind of like how `\[\mbox{$\prod_i$}\]` produces an inline `prod` even though the "parent" environment is display maths.

Comment: Oh @DaiBowen, I am sorry. I leave the answer, it can be helpful thanks to your comment